# Setting up SQLite for Core.Data and saving a User entity in another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, ios7

How do I go about setting up a Core.Data database in ios7 while my data is executing on another thread?

I have code like this:

```
// Create thread
dispatch_queue_t uniqueQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Unique Email Queue", NULL);

// Run block on another thread called downloadQueue
dispatch_async(uniqueQueue, ^{

    // I have the following strings that I want to save into a User entity that is already created
    NSString *username = [emailStr lowercaseString];
    NSString *password = passwordStr;
    NSString *email = emailStr;
    NSString *name = nameStr;

});
```

My entity User in the model has all those fields created, and has a createdOn and updatedOn date set as NSDate.

How do I initialize a SQLite database and save that data uniquely to my database?  I've tried a bunch of different methods so far, like using AppDelegate, etc.  Everything crashes.

Is there a good answer to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you are using to set up the Core Data stack.

Comment: Multithreading with coredata, hmm the best solution i found was magical record. Try it https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord and tutorials here http://maniacdev.com/2012/04/tutorial-the-basics-of-using-the-magical-record-core-data-library

Comment: So is common practice to save the managedObjectContext and the saved data in the main thread? Does it affect the UI responsiveness at all or much?